# Simple Form not posting to DB Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a simple form which is shown below

```
<% title("Home Page") %>
<h1><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Add Event <small>views/pages/home.html.erb</small></h1>
<div class="row">
  <%= simple_form_for(@newevent) do |f| %>
     <%= f.input :eventname, required: true %>
     <%= f.input :eventdate %>
     <%= f.input :eventimage %>
     <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My controller is this

```
class AddController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @newevent = Newevent.new
  end
end
```

And this is my model

```
class Newevent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :event
  def event_params
      params.require(:newevents).permit(:eventname, :eventdate, :eventimage)
    end
end
```

Any ideas on why this isn't working? I've not tried adding in  any pry's or byebugs because im not 100% sure on how to use them yet.

Comment: your code is not looking proper, check this http://railscasts.com/episodes/234-simple-form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Resourceful**

Firstly, you need to appreciate the [*resourceful* nature of Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default):

[image]

You're currently using the following:

```
class AddController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @newevent = Newevent.new
  end
end
```

This goes against the convention, and is likely one of the contributing reasons to the issue. I would use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :events

#app/controllers/events_controller.rb
class EventsController < ActionController::Base
   def new
       @event = Event.new
   end
   def create
       @event = Event.new event_params
       @event.save
   end
end
```

The reason this is important is because helpers, such as `form_for` and `simple_form_for` are built around the object-orientated nature of Ruby, and Rails.

When you use `simple_form_for(@event)`, it's not a shot in the dark - the helpers do their best to translate the object into a HTML form.

If the object does not work to convention (IE there is no `create` route/action), you're going to get a problem.

---

**Controller**

Secondly, you need to consider what you're actually doing in your controller

You've given us one controller action which only sets a new object. It doesn't do anything with that object, which is where saving to the DB would actually work.

You need something like this:

```
#app/controllers/events_controller.rb
class EventsController < ActionController::Base
   def new
       @event = Event.new
   end

   def create
       @event = Event.new event_params
       @event.save #-> add some conditional logic for if the event is saved etc
   end

   def show
       @event = Event.find params[:id]
   end

   private

    def event_params
      params.require(:newevents).permit(:eventname, :eventdate, :eventimage)
    end
end
```

This will give you the ability to create the following views:

```
#app/views/events/new.html.erb -> yoururl.com/events/new
<%= simple_form_for(@event) do |f| %>
     <%= f.input :name, required: true %>
     <%= f.input :date %>
     <%= f.input :image %>
     <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/views/events/show.html.erb
<%= @event.name %>
```

This will be accompanied by your `Event` model:

```
#app/models/event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

---

**Form**

Thirdly, you need to ensure your form is submitting properly.

I think you need to change `<%= f.button %>` to `<%= f.submit %>`. This will create the correct HTML form elements, which should submit them properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code.

First, you places the `event_params` in your model, but your model has no idea what `params` is. You have access to the request `params` in the controller, not in the model.

Second, your view has a form that will likely send to a create action (as this is the default in Rails for forms around new objects. And not only you have no create actions in your controller, but there is no evidence of a route for it nor code that performs a creation of the model.

Last but not least, you never access the request params in the controller.

You just glued together a few lines of code and you are pretending that they will magically work, but from the code it seems you have no idea at all how Rails works.

Before proceeding further with your app, I encourage you to start from the basics by reading a book about Ruby and one about Rails so that you will have a basic understanding on how the language and the framework works before attempting to use it.

Also, don't introduce extra complexity (such as the simple form plugin) until you understand how the main framework works, otherwise it will be even more complicated to debug issues.